# I'm getting spurious ("field is required", when field has been set!) validation messages from KendoUI dropdown lists/EditorTemplates - how to solve?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

(This is a copy of a support question I put to Telerik and the solution, because as far as I can tell, Telerik have not informed their users of the problem so far.)

I have an MVC project which uses kendoui grids in lots of places, including some fields which use custom EditorTemplates to produce dropdown lists for the user to select from, and in several cases there are cascading fields, with Field 1 having .EditorTemplateName("template1") and Field2 having  .EditorTemplateName("template2") where template 2 cascades from the value of Field1.

This has worked fine for several months until now, but recently (in fact since I upgraded to version 2015.1.318 of UI for ASP.NET MVC) what seems to happen is that often (but not always!) when I create a new record, the validation errors are there for fields 1 and 2 saying that they are required (which is correct), I then complete Field1 and I'm then able to complete Field2 (in each case be selecting from the dropdown lists), but then when I click Update to save (I'm using inline editing in the grid), I still get the validation error messages saying that Field1 and Field2 are required, even though they have been set!

If I then go to Field1 and change it from its selected value back to "select ..." and then to my desired value, and similarly with Field2, it does then seem as if I can click the Update button and the record will be saved.

Any idea how I can fix this?  Is there a problem with version 2015.1.318, eg with its standard EditorTemplates?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The solution was that the latest version (2015.1.318) seems to be causing the problem, and Telerik support suggested that I download the latest internal release (2015.1.327), which I did and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Why are the question and answer attracting negative points (-1 and -2 respectively at the moment)?  Surely it was useful to report the problem and its solution at the time, even if the problem has almost certainly now gone away since Telerik have released newer versions?